# Braintree testing, can't get braintree to reject card

Tags: php, braintree

It must be something simple but I'm pulling my hair out. When I call this

```
$data = [
        'amount' => '50.00',
        'paymentMethodNonce' => 'fake-processor-declined-mastercard-nonce',
        'options' => [
            'submitForSettlement' => true
        ]
    ];

    $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale($data);
```

I get back "success" from Braintree. How do I get the card declined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out that on the `Braintree_Transaction::sale` method using the fake-nonce isn't the way you do it. You do it with the amount. You match the amount to the error code you want to produce. So an amount of `2001.00` will get a response of `"Insufficient Funds"`. A list of error codes can be found [here](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/declines#authorization-decline-codes)

Comment: So, what is the purpose of those 'fake-processor-declined-visa-nonce' values then? To confuse users? That has been driving me nuts recently!

Comment: I was not aware that that amount corresponds with the code you want to simulate up until this point. I still have no idea where this is documented. But it works. Thanks for the correct answer!